# Unable to log into Hulu through Chrome because "Location is turned off in Mac System Preferences", but setting is on and still won't let me in

Tags: security, google-chrome, privacy, preferences, geolocation

I am trying to log into Hulu with Chrome and it asks to share my location. I say yes. It goes to log in and I get a popup for a location request. I accept and the browser says my location has been shared but a little icon of the waypoint with an X on it pops up saying "Location is turned off in Mac system preferences". However, when I open my Mac System Preferences, everything is turned on. I can watch Hulu in Safari and it accepted the location preferences but on Chrome there seems to be an issue.

Comment: That's some good diagnostic work on your part.  You've successfully, by process of elimination, narrowed the issue down to Chrome.  I would start looking through the settings within Chrome to see if location is disabled there.  If not, you might have an issue with the browser itself.  If you have difficulty and still need to use Chrome, have a look at Microsoft Edge as it's built on the same Chromium engine

Comment: .. Or see if another browser, not based on Chromium, works better. Vivaldi, Firefox, Safari, etc. However, there is a flaw relating to Location Services in the latest update to Ventura (13.5), which may be a factor.

Comment: @benwiggy 13.5.1 was released yesterday to fix this. Alenity, if you haven't upgraded to 13.5.1 yet, please do so and try again. If it still doesn't work, try a different browser.